# will SLES sles10x2 2.6.16.46-0.12-smp version support gcc7

Tags: gcc, operating-system, sles

I have a SLES OS :  sles10x2 2.6.16.46-0.12-smp. Will it support upgrading to gcc7?
Currently it is having gcc4.1.2. I am trying to evaluate if I can upgrade it to gcc7 and what will be the other impacts if upgrade is possible.

Answer (score 0):

According to https://www.suse.com/lifecycle SLES10 is out of support since a few years. So the answer to your question is: no.